# meaning of "?" in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I've seen some (my)sql queries written like this:

```
SELECT ? + 4;
```

What's the meaning of `?` ? My guess is it's some kind of parameter, but how does one specify the value for it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`?` is a placeholder for parameter values in the [syntax for prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html). The linked article gives the following example:

> ```
> mysql> PREPARE stmt1 FROM 'SELECT SQRT(POW(?,2) + POW(?,2)) AS hypotenuse';
> mysql> SET @a = 3;
> mysql> SET @b = 4;
> mysql> EXECUTE stmt1 USING @a, @b;
> +------------+
> | hypotenuse |
> +------------+
> |          5 |
> +------------+
> mysql> DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
> ```

Since you also tagged [sql](/questions/tagged/sql), it's worth linking to the [Prepared Statement Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) for further reading independent of MySQL.

Comment: So `?` can only be used in prepare statement?

Comment: @user1508893 Yes, there's no other use for them to my knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

In mysql a `?` is a placeholder in a [prepared statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html). It will be replaced by whatever value is bound from the client before the statement is executed.